# My blender keep crashing after i change the rendering to GPU rendering from Preference tab

Tags: modeling, rendering, edit-mode, customization

i was trying few different settings for blender for rendering but i end up having major crash and now my Blender is not working anymore. it keep crashing.
I changed the Rendering setting from normal to Open GL 3.3 i think this was the version (Blender 2.9.2).
after i done that i run a render and my GPU crash and the PC got restarted After that it start crashing.
i try to download new version but same
Here is the Error i am facing. [image]
Can someone help Please.
Thank you

Comment: PS i was using AMD RX580 8GB

Comment: GPU is definitely not problem (speaking of type) because I am using the same at my home rig and it works fine with OpenCL and cycles using GPU. Did you actually tried to update or downgrade drivers? You didn't mention it in your question

Comment: Reloading or reinstalling won't change your preferences, and newer versions of blender auto save preferences by default, so it's probably  that the change you made causing the crash is still present.  Can you open blender and edit your preferences and redo the settings for graphics?